# Define a String array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, program-entry-point

In java we can define `main()` method as both these ways.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {          
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

.

```
public static void main(String... args) {          
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Both method takes `array` of `String` arguments. Now consider following scenario.

```
    String[] arr=new String[10]; // valid
    String... arr=new String[10];// invalid
```

`Java` never allows to create an array like this way`String... arr=new String[10];`. But in above method implementation `java` allows to do so. My question is how `java` achieve this two different behavior for two scenarios?

Comment: I liked the question, hence upvoted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...
```

is a syntax for method arguments and not for variable definitions. The name of this notation is [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), which is self explanatory i.e variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

**[Variable argument or varargs(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)** in Java used to write more flexible methods which can accept as many argument as you need not for initialization.

Answer (score 1):

`...` refers to **varargs** and its main intention to make method **more readable**.

```
void method(String... args) {

}
```

can be called as

`method("a");` OR `method("a", "b");` OR `method("a", "b", "c");`

I see no point in using it in variable declaration, we can't do much with

```
String... a = {"a", "b"}
```

An array can anyways be declared with dynamic size

```
String[] arr = {"a"};
```

OR

```
String[] arr = {"a", "b"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use varargs in `main` because a method declared with varargs (...) is bytecode compatible with a declaration of a method with an array argument (for backwards compatibility). That does not mean that the same syntax is allowed for type declarations.